# Using a Common Scope Between a Directive and a Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to create a svg shape, which is a circle and read the specification, e.g. radius or center coordinates, from the scope of the application which exists in html document:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" >
<div id="body"  ng-controller="testCtrl">
    cx: <input type="number" ng-model="cx"/><br/>
    cy: <input type="number" ng-model="cy"/><br/>
    R : <input type="number" ng-model="radius" />

    <draggable-circle/>
</div>
</div>
```

Also the controller of the application is:

```
 var testCtrl = angularApp.controller('testCtrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.cx = 100, $scope.cy = 100, $scope.radius = 50;
     });
```

And the directive is:

```
 testCtrl.directive('draggableCircle', function () {
       function link(scope, el, attr) {
        var w = 600, h = 400;
        var drag = d3.behavior.drag().origin(Object).on("drag", dragmove);
           var svg = d3.select(el[0]).append("svg")
                        .attr("class", "svgContainer")
                        .attr("width", w)
                        .attr("height", h);
         var newg = svg.append("g").data([{ x: scope.cx , y: scope.cy}]);

         var dragCircle = newg.append("circle")
                        .attr("r", scope.radius)
                        .attr("cx", function(d) {
                            return d.x;
                        })
                        .attr("cy", function (d) {
                            return d.y;
                        })
                        .attr("fill", "red")
                        .style("fill-opacity", 0.8)
                        .style("stroke", "steelblue")
                        .style("cursor"," pointer")
                        .call(drag);
         function dragmove(d) {
            var mousePosition = d3.mouse(this);
           dragCircle.attr("cx", d.x =scope.cx= mousePosition[0])
               .attr("cy", d.y=scope.cy = mousePosition[1]);
                        scope.$apply()
         }
       }
         return {
                    link: link
                };
     });
```

The problem is, when the values of the coordinates are changed by the controller, the shape must be changed in the directive. but it is not working as I expected. In addition, when the shape is dragged by user, the values which are changed in the directive, automatically broadcast to the controller and model, because of using `scope.$apply()`, which I think is not the best solution.
I want to make a duplex connection, i.e. when the specification is changed in the directive, it affects controller and vice versa. Also I want to implement the best solution for this goal.

Plunker link: http://plnkr.co/edit/3itxi9DSvGHJzyRRvrUr?p=preview

**UPDATE**

I want to bind the controls and the shape together, which means the shape coordinates are changed due to change the value of the controls, which are bound to the model, and vice versa.

Comment: You can access the controller scope if your directive is a child of the controller by using scope.$parent from within the directive. This might be what you're looking for.

Comment: could you make a service for the value? Then just have everything that needs the value subscribe to the service?

Answer (score 0):

Saman,

You can use this concept called [accessor](https://blog.tallan.com/2014/11/03/bidirectional-communication-between-directives-and-controllers-in-angular/). It works just fine and it is a lightweight solution. You won't need to overuse `$watch` and `$broadcast` or `$emit`

Comment: May I ask you to check the plnkr link and change that so I can understand the solution please?

Comment: Saman, check [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/TtgCHoGnl5uuX1twa5ni?p=preview) out. It is a little messy but it shows you how to do it. Avoid using `$watch` when possible

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not about scopes at all; The problem is you registered the `dragmove` function as a callback.
This callback was not registered in an AngulasJs environment, and that is the reason you need to use `$apply`. When this callback makes a change to your scope variable, the angular framework is not aware of it unless you call `$apply`. This is a common problem when you are using a non-angular lib along with angular code.

I think you are in the right way; Probably all you need now is something like

```
function updatePosition(){ 
    dragCircle.attr("cx", d.x =scope.cx)
           .attr("cy", d.y=scope.cy);
}

$scope.$watch('cx', updatePosition);
$scope.$watch('cy', updatePosition);
```

If there is any problem with this please let me know because I never used d3.js, so I might be unaware of something else that's going on in there.

Answer (score 0):

You should to read about [isolated scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). After that you need to $watch properties from the controller in the directive, and after applying them make $scope.apply, that will not cause the parent scope, because object is in the isolated scope.

I've made a plunk for you:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div id="body" ng-controller="testCtrl">
        cx:         <input type="number" ng-model="initial.cx" />
        <br />

        cy:         <input type="number" ng-model="initial.cy" />
        <br />

        R :         <input type="number" ng-model="initial.radius" />
        <draggable-circle initial="initial"></draggable-circle>
    </div>
</div>
<script>

    var angularApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    var testCtrl = angularApp.controller('testCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.initial = {};
        $scope.initial.cx = 100;
        $scope.initial.cy = 100;
        $scope.initial.radius = 50;
    });

    testCtrl.directive('draggableCircle', function () {
        function link(scope, el, attr) {

            var w = 600, h = 400;
            var drag = d3.behavior.drag().origin(Object).on("drag", dragmove);

            var svg = d3.select(el[0]).append("svg")
                    .attr("class", "svgContainer")
                    .attr("width", w)
                    .attr("height", h);
            var newg = svg.append("g").data([{ x: scope.initial.cx , y: scope.initial.cy}]);

            var dragCircle = newg.append("circle")
                    .attr("r", scope.initial.radius)
                    .attr("cx", function(d) {
                        return d.x;
                    })
                    .attr("cy", function (d) {
                        return d.y;
                    })
                    .attr("fill", "red")
                    .style("fill-opacity", 0.8)
                    .style("stroke", "steelblue")
                    .style("cursor"," pointer")
                    .call(drag);

            scope.$watch('initial.cx', applyNewProperties);
            scope.$watch('initial.cy', applyNewProperties);

            function applyNewProperties() {
                dragCircle.attr("cx", scope.initial.cx)
                        .attr("cy", scope.initial.cy);
            }


            function dragmove(d) {
                console.log(scope.initial);
                var mousePosition = d3.mouse(this);
                dragCircle.attr("cx", d.x =scope.cx = scope.initial.cx = mousePosition[0])
                        .attr("cy", d.y=scope.cy =  scope.initial.cy =mousePosition[1]);
                scope.$apply()
            }
        }
        return {
            link: link,
            scope: {
                initial: '='
            }
        };

    });
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but It's working just when I change the controls! It should work also when the shape is dragged and update the value of control with the current values of the shape.

Comment: I've edited the script. It's working as you wanted for now. But this script is just for showing the idea. I would rather change for the production.

Comment: So i didn't understood you for the first time :) You just needed the $watch.

Comment: Now the problem is solved! Thank you, but I think it's not the best solution, it's just a really simple sample, in the real project I have about 50 properties! I don't want to write $watch 50 times!

Comment: Use the $watchCollection for it.

Answer (score 0):

I read all of the answers, they are near to the solution but none of them is the right one. So, I've changed the Plunker to this:

```
scope.$watch('coord', updateCoord,true);

function updateCoord() {
      dragCircle.attr("cx", scope.coord.cx)
        .attr("cy", scope.coord.cy).attr("r",scope.coord.radius);
 }


function dragmove(d) {
    var mousePosition = d3.mouse(this);
    dragCircle.attr("cx", d.x  = scope.coord.cx = mousePosition[0])
         .attr("cy", d.y =  scope.coord.cy =mousePosition[1]);
                scope.$apply();
 }
```

The point is, to observe the model for changes you need to use `$watch(... ,true)` which is monitoring all of the changes.

This is the new Punkler: http://plnkr.co/edit/X9uDMLmSUuCD1bLdv5Ml?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I forked your  [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OuyiG7rDl2DVpC0hZvBQ?p=preview)

Added a update function and one watcher. It is working now

```
 function update() {
    dragCircle = newg.selectAll("circle")
                .attr("r", scope.data.radius)
                .attr("cx", scope.data.cx)
                .attr("cy", scope.data.cy)
                .call(drag);
 }
```

Please check the plunker link for full code